# how to register assemblies and query data

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

**Does Data Lake support registering assemblies? What is wrong with my approach?**

After attempting to go through [this](https://www.taygan.co/blog/2018/01/06/azure-data-lake-series-working-with-json-part-1) tutorial, I've been road blocked by this error:

> E_CSC_USER_CANNOTREADASSEMBLY: Assembly file
>   'adl://alidadelakestordev.azuredatalakestore.net/myfilesystem/Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
>   could not be read.

I've attempted many different combinations of `adl` / `wasb` / `https` for the URI, yet no luck:

[image]

Here's the complete script I am using:

```
// A. CREATE ASSEMBLY: Register assemblies (if they do not already exist).
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Newtonsoft.Json] FROM "adl://alidadelakestordev.azuredatalakestore.net/myfilesystem/Newtonsoft.Json.dll";
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats] FROM "adl://alidadelakestordev.azuredatalakestore.net/myfilesystem/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll";

// B. REFERENCE ASSEMBLY: Load assemblies for compile time and execution.
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

// C. USING: Specify namespace to shorten function names (e.g. Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor)
USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

// 1. Initialise variables for Input (e.g. JSON) and Output (e.g. CSV).
DECLARE @InputFile string = "adl://alidadelakestordev.azuredatalakestore.net/myfilesystem/exercise01.json";
DECLARE @OutputFile string = "adl://alidadelakestordev.azuredatalakestore.net/myfilesystem/exercise01.csv";

// 2. Extract string content from JSON document (i.e. schema on read).
@json =
EXTRACT
    title string,
    rating string,
    genre string,
    year string
FROM
    @InputFile
USING new JsonExtractor();

// 3. Write values to CSV
OUTPUT @json
TO @OutputFile
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader:true,quoting:true);
```

I've created a `Gen2` storage account, created a container, and uploaded my assemblies as well as my input file:

[image]

The error persists `CANNOTREADASSEMBLY`:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of data explorer:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? How do I register assemblies?**

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this we just register the Assembly with this script.

- Create the database so we are ensure that we have the needed assembly's where we want.

```cs
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MyDB; 

USE DATABASE MyDB;
```

- Then we create the assembly:

```cs
DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS [Newtonsoft.Json];
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json] FROM @"CFG/Assemblies/Newtonsoft.Json.dll";

DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats] FROM @"CFG/Assemblies/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll";
```

- Then we run the script in the data lake to register it (after our project is build and release, the script run automatically).
- After the assemblys registered we just use this database in our scripts before the reference os the assemblys.

```cs
// Feature for data to be partioned by key we will choose (diferent output paths).
SET @@FeaturePreviews = "DataPartitionedOutput:on";

/* ====================================================================================== */
/* Database */
/* ====================================================================================== */

USE DATABASE MyDB;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Reference and Load Assemblies
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to register assembly in U-SQL Catalog, so you should create a database also. 
Follow these steps

```
DECLARE @ASSEMBLY_PATH string = "/upload/asm/spatial/";
DECLARE @SPATIAL_ASM string = @ASSEMBLY_PATH+"Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll";
DECLARE @SPATIAL_NATIVEDLL string = @ASSEMBLY_PATH+"SqlServerSpatial130.dll";

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS SQLSpatial;
USE DATABASE SQLSpatial;

    DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS SqlSpatial;
    CREATE ASSEMBLY SqlSpatial
    FROM @SPATIAL_ASM
    WITH ADDITIONAL FILES =
         (
             @SPATIAL_NATIVEDLL
        );
```

Comment: how do we proceed after we create this database?

Comment: you just define on the top of the script USE DATABASE [YourDatabase]; and then you can reference assembly that is registered in your catalog. (your code from reference assembly is fine)